# How can I automate the calculation for P and I coefficients of an FPGA-based digital PLL?

Tags: filter-design, signal-detection, digital, pll

I am working on designing an FPGA-based PLL through an NI myRI0-1900 FPGA and LabVIEW software. I have been able to create a functioning PLL with a PI loop filter, and but I found functioning P and I coefficients through trial and error for a 1kHz signal, However, when I try to have my program compute the P and I coefficients with equations listed below, the values are too large for the PLL to be stable.

As background on my algorithm, I have a pipeline of various loops setup where I read an external sample through an ADC, mix it with NCO signals to create I and Q signals, send these through an LIA algorithm to recover the phase difference between the NCO and ADC, send this error signal through a PI control, then send the post-PI signal back to the NCO so that it can increment/decrement its phase (frequency) towards the external signal that is being tracked. I output this NCO signal through a DAC.

Now, for a 1kHz external signal, I have found that a P coefficient of around 3.50E-6, and an I coefficient of around 1.00E-8 works pretty well. These coefficients scale the phase difference between the NCO and ADC, and the result is summed up and sent to the phase accumulator. The way I found this was by starting with an I coefficient of 0, and a very small P, then I made the P larger and larger until it worked relatively well. Afterwards, I kept the P constant, and I then made the I coefficient very small before making it larger.

However, I want to calculate these P and I values for my system so that I may automatically adapt their values to work well for the frequency of the ADC signal. The first equation below is one that I found for calculating the Kp, while the second is for the ENBW, of which Kp is a function of. My equations were found from the following link: https://wirelesspi.com/phase-locked-loop-pll-in-a-software-defined-radio-sdr/

[image: Equation for ENBW (Bn). zeta is damping factor and w is angular frequency]
[image: Equations for Kp and Ki. KD is gain of the phase error detector, K0 is the NCO gain, Bn is ENBW, and Fs is sampling rate]

For (what I believe to be) the sampling rate, Fs, I found it through the following. I set the loops in my pipeline to all take 120 ticks to iterate, where 1 tick = 25ns. Thus, each loop takes 3 microseconds, and I can manage 333.3 kSa/s - a sampling rate of 333.3 kHz.

For the w in the Bn, I used (2pi * f), where f is the frequency in Hz of my ADC signal (I have a separate algorithm that can track this frequency well, so I don't need to manually input this). For testing, I use a 1 kHz ADC signal.

For the Bn (the ENBW), I used the equation for it below, but with a damping factor of 0.7071. And assuming that f = 1kHz, then my Bn evaluates to 1060.66.

For the K0 and KD, they are 1 and 1/2, respectively.

Finally, I plug these numbers into the equations above so that I can solve for the Kp, but my answer, is 0.0170, which is far larger than the 1E-7 that works well. How may I achieve an answer around the 1E-7? Is my math process logical? Could some of my variables be incorrect?

Please let me know of any questions or concerns. I would be obliged to assist.